# Kendo grid with date column not sorting correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a column that is a DateTime? type.  When sorting on this column the dates are not sorting correctly.  It appears to be sorting with respect to month not with respect to the whole date.  Is there some sort of magic that needs to be done in order for it to sort on the whole date and not just the month and day?  Below is the table.  The Paymentdate column is the DateTime? field that I'm trying to sort on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PaymentTransactionViewModel>()
            .Name("payment-history-list")
            .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "js-table-accordion accordion-table detail-table" })
            .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.Bound(p => p.PaymentDate).Title("Payment Date").Format("{0:d").Sortable(true);
                c.Bound(p => p.Amount).Format("{0:c}").Title("Amount").Sortable(false);
                c.Bound(p => p.BankAccountNickName).Title("Bank Account").Sortable(false);
                c.Bound(p => p.ConfirmationId).Title("Confirmation ID").Sortable(false);
            })
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
        )
```

Comment: what format is you date being shown? can you post screen of how it is being shown vs how it should be shown?

Comment: The format of the date is showing correctly as MM/dd/yyyy.  The problem is, is when I click the column to sort the order is out of date.  Lowest to highest will show as follows:

01/04/2016
02/05/2015
02/10/2016.. ect

It isn't sorting in correct order.

Comment: try changing Format to {0 : MM/dd/yyyy}.. also you are missing a "}" in your format

Comment: I tried {0 : MM/dd/yyyy} instead of {0:d} with the same result

Comment: but is it a typo are you are missing a closing curly bracket?

Comment: No I had fixed that before.

Comment: Try this format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

Comment: @Alex same result

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the format "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
Google Chrome receive the data using this template, and than check your language configuration to display in the correct way.

Comment: No luck, same result

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and literally, I thought that there is a bug with kendo. 
The reason was that I had a `DateTime ContractDate` and a `string contractDate` in my model.I just changed the name of `string` to something else like `contractDateStr`.
I don't know why but Kendo was picking the string `contractDate` instead of `ContractDate`.